# How to delete the default Firebase instance in React Native and reinitialize it at runtime?

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am working on a project where I need to set certain attributes from the Firebase project, such as the sender ID from the Firebase configuration at runtime. After that, I need to obtain the FCM token to receive push notifications.

I'm using react-native 0.70.0 and https://rnfirebase.io/.

Any help? pls!!

I've tried to delete the default app and reinitialize it, but I think it's not possible. I've also attempted to initialize another instance apart from the DEFAULT one, and it's possible, but it's not possible to receive push notifications from a different instance other than the DEFAULT one.

Comment: "I've tried to delete the default app and reinitialize it, but I think it's not possible." Please edit your question to show what you tried, and the result you got from that. Also see: [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/issues/2991